# How Can I Recreate Steppenwolf's Armor Pattern?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

How can I recreate Justice League: Snyder Cut's Steppenwolf armor pattern to wrap around any surface and animate contracting and pulsing? I imagine Geo-Nodes, but I'm not yet good enough to design my own systems. What kind of wonderful ideas do you guys have? Here's a model off of Sketchfab for reference:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/steppenwolf-bust-9eb2f6d1b03c43558fd1148dcf7be053

.. and a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometry nodes is indeed a good way to do things like this. You can for example instance a piece along a curve. That way you can access all the curve informations and translate them on the instances which allows you to do quite a lot of operations.

Here is an example of what I did :

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I am instancing this simple mesh along a bezier curve. I am then using the index of each point of the curve to offset the rotation of each instances and give it a "pulstating" effect (if that's what you were refering to)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is so sick and exactly as effective as I wanted. Thank you!